# Integration of Cruise Control.Net with Wix

Tags: svn, msbuild, wix, cruisecontrol.net, cruisecontrol

I am using cruise control.net for updating version in svn and for building projects using msbuild . after that I use wix to create a patch by comparing old and new .wixpdbs by sending commands in postbuild event.

**I want to automate incremental patch development process with each svn update** , so is there any plugin or way to integrate cruise control with Wix. So that with each .wixpdb file generated by Wix's light.exe can be stored in separate folder with their version name automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The build publisher
http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Build_Publisher

this allows you to copy any kind of files under a version subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

One way to make the patching process easier is by using `.wixout` files rather than `.wixpdb` files when building patches, as it no longer requires a precise directory structure to be maintained. Please see the following relevant answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50912893/2791491) for more details.